# AlarmManager not waking from deep sleep

Tags: android, alarmmanager

The code for setting the alarm is:

```
mAlarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), interval, getPendingIntent());
```

I tried also

```
mAlarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), interval, getPendingIntent());
```

Where

```
interval = type long of ~60000
cal = Calendar.getInstance() then modified DAY, HOUR etc.
```

I've noticed that my alarm doesn't trigger if phone in deep sleep at all.

I also checked command
    adb shell dumpsys alarm

And alarm is written in and should start at time selected. Where's the catch then that alarm sometimes does, sometimes doesn't trigger?

BroadcastReceiver works as it should since i'm logging other possible actions too:

```
public class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        // some things here...
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml includes permissions for:

```
    android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM
```

This is really confusing and Serious issue for my app...

Comment: have you added SET_ALARM to your project manifest?

Comment: Hi, sorry I haven't added this to OP ˙<uses-permission android:name="android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM" />˙ is in manifest file.

Comment: Hi, have you fixed it?